# ASP.NET - ListView binding - Clarification

Tags: asp.net, listview, binding

We have an ASP.NET application and using a ListView to display some user records from the database.

Once we populate the ListView from the database the user can edit few/more records of it.

Now our requirement is that once the user edits a record we need post those changes to the database but should not rebind the ListView (from the database).  We also should not use a Cache or Session object to store the data of ListView.

Do you think that it is possible?  If so would you please guide / refer a code sample on this?

Comment: Please explain your current data access technique to get the original DataSource data for the list. Maybe that will give us some ideas on some filtering/storing techniques you could use to always get back to that same set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 data sets. Consider data set 1 (D1) and data set 2 (D2).

Bind the `ListView` with D1, once the user edits D1.

Copy D1 to D2, accept changes on D2.

But reject the changes in D1, so it will be with old values. Bind that to listview.

But the database has been updated using D2.

-- But tell me why you want do it like this? Whenever the user edits something it should reflect both on his/her screen and the database, then only there should there be consistency between data.